# How to change figure according to rhythm?

Tags: game-maker

How to change figure according to rhythm ?

for example if there is hexagon, this hexagon is beating according to rhythm like 'Super Hexagon' game

Comment: This is far too broad. Do you have a specific programming question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you know 'Super Hexagon' game?  I want to make like this game.

Comment: I do. That doesn't change the fact that this question is too broad though. You're after some sort of tutorial by the sounds of it which is off topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a go yourself and run in to specific coding issues, please do post those questions here, but I'm afraid it's very unlikely anyone here will tell you how to make a super hexagon like game from the ground up.

Comment: If you're particularly interested in how to animate certain frames based on the rhythm of the music, you could consider asking that on the [Programmers exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) where conceptual questions are welcome :).

Comment: The basic algorithm would be that you would store the BPM of the music, in some datastructure, with information on the bg music. Then from this BPM value, you can sync to the refresh as you know the rythm. Let us say that bg music is 120BPM, this means 2 main beats per second. Now you can use this to refresh your object (i.e. change size to make it pulse) in sync with this. For this to work out you basically have to sync your rendering to the screen as well.